# Unable to find error in css file

Tags: css, rspec, sass, capybara

I'm trying to use RSpec to write some feature test. In my application I use buyed template. It has a lot of styles. When I trying to run specs I have the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       Invalid CSS after "  display": expected ";", was ":block !important;"
         (in /home/mateusz/invoiceplus/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
     # (sass):9074
     # ./app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__3446440732480765705_58447420'
     # ./spec/features/creating_companies_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem because this file with css styles has around 5 thousands lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error was before the "display" property (perhaps a missing comma?) and it tries to parse the "display" as a value to the previous property. Perhaps grep your file for "[^,] *display"?

If you've found it, add the comma before `display:block !important`, and it should work.